# FireStore not working with Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I tried to print out all data in my `users` collection of firestore. But always, it returns `{}` this.

```
exports.trial = functions.https.onRequest( (request, response) => {
    // var db = admin.firestore();
    admin.firestore().collection("/users").get().then( snapshot => {
        response.send(snapshot);
    }).catch(error => {
        response.send(error);
    });
} );
```

I tried to make read, write public but none is working. May be I am missing something. I am running functions locally.

Comment: What error/unexpected behavior are you seeing?

Comment: `admin.firestore().collection("users")` ...

Comment: @MartinZeitler that print `{"_query":{"_firestore":{"projectId":"project-trial"},"_queryOptions":{"parentPath":{"segments":[]},"collectionId":"users","converter":{},"allDescendants":false,"fieldFilters":[],"fieldOrders":[],"kindless":false,"requireConsistency":true},"_serializer":{"allowUndefined":false},"_allowUndefined":false},"_readTime":{"_seconds":1628512388,"_nanoseconds":351959000},"_size":1,"_materializedDocs":null,"_materializedChanges":null}`

Comment: @LuizFerraz I do not got any error. But always it give empty json. `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `snapshot` variable is a `QuerySnapshot` object, which is not a valid JSON object. You probably want to send the documents in the snapshot back, which you can do with:

```
response.send(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()))
```

Comment: Thanks @theTerribleSWE for the suggestion on using `map` to return only the data from each document.